# how to make a calculator with python like in c++

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, wxpython, ipython

i want to make a calculator to "/","*",and "+" so i write my code like that

```
x,op,y=raw_input()
if op=='+':
  print int(x)+int(y)
```

here if i enter number have two digit it will make error i should enter digit less than 10 form 0 to 9 only to make plus or minus and so on so i tried to split them like this

```
x,op,y=raw_input().split()
if op=='+':
  print int(x)+int(y)
```

put the input will be like 20 + 20 here is the problem i want to remove this space between the number more than 9 to make the operation i want the input like 20+20 not 20 + 20 on them so i can submit the code on the online judge help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you actually need to parse the expression yourself?  What about

```
expression = raw_input()
answer = eval(expression)
print answer
```

?

You could use `try:` and catch exceptions and do something sensible if the default exception raising isn't the behavior you want.  (Like, for instance, if the expression ends up being `asdf'.8` or some other garbage expression, you might want a different behavior from the default `SyntaxError`.)

Note: a criticism of the approach I suggest above is it allows potentially malicious strings to be evaluated, so it might make sense to sanitize your input first...

Comment: can you tell me how to make this to float number to improve my knowledge

Comment: when i divide 12/5 for example it print 2 i want 2.4 float number and many thanks my bro

Comment: good answer I thought about putting this but decided against it ... but it works fine

Comment: Several things will work, Amr —
you could do `12. / 5` (i.e., explicitly make one of them a float by using a decimal point), or `float(12) / 5`, or `from __future__ import division` since in Python 3 the default behavior for integer division is to create floats when the remainder is nonzero, instead of truncating.

Answer (score 0):

try `re.split("([+-/*])",raw_input())` maybe ?

```
my_input = raw_input()
numbers = re.split("([+-/*])", my_input)
if '+' in my_input:
    print float(numbers[0]) + float(numbers[1])
```

or

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split("\s*([+-/*])\s*",raw_input())
29+ 22
['29', '+', '22']
```

Comment: nice to see u after long time brother. but he will loose operator here

Comment: how can i use it ??? iwant all on one raw the input is  like this 20+20 to print 40 i want to enter this sting called op between this 2 integer if this string "+" it make + and so on

Comment: @Hackaholic no he shouldnt since it uses a capture group :) good seeing you